# What is the best way to get the boundary of an array of data in VBA excel?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, boundary

I wrote a code in VBA that gets the last boundary of data array in excel. I assumed that the array begins with the cell "A1" :

```
Function getBoundary()

Dim boundaryPoint(2)
boundaryPoint(0) = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
boundaryPoint(1) = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
getBoundary = boundaryPoint
```

End Function

I want to know if there is a better way to do it and if my code is optimized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [`CurrentRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx):

```
Dim boundaryPoint(2) As Long, r As Range

Set r = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

boundaryPoint(0) = r.Rows.Count
boundaryPoint(1) = r.Columns.Count
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)